# LeafletJS multi-polyline in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I'm trying to use the demo from http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#polyline

```
// create a red polyline from an array of LatLng points
var latlngs = [
    [45.51, -122.68],
    [37.77, -122.43],
    [34.04, -118.2]
];
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
// zoom the map to the polyline
map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
```

However, it's throwing me an error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'number[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LatLngExpression[]'.
  Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'LatLngExpression'.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
      Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]'.
```

is something else needed when using leaflet with Angular/TypeScript?

Answer (score 14):

Looks like your code is fine, but the types are a little finicky. As the compiler notes, `number[]` is not assignable to `[number, number]`, which makes total sense (as an empty array `[]` should assign to `number[]` but not `[number, number]`).

Anyway, all you have to do is give typescript a hint that you are actually passing the right type. I would recommend you declare it on your variable, eg:

```
var latlngs: [number, number][] = [
    [45.51, -122.68],
    [37.77, -122.43],
    [34.04, -118.2]
];
```

Or, if in your actual use case that value comes from somewhere else, you can just cast it:

```
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs as [number, number][], {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Both of those would have worked :) but as I'm now passing the array through a method param, if I leave the param undeclared it stops complaining!